# Shopping through phone call

Tags: backend, shopping-cart

How to implement backend user registration for buyers who wish to use telephonic service to buy a product from my online shop. How do I go about it? I need backend management of specific user data and inventory management based on the telephonic purchases.
-edit-
For further clarity on question: instead of web interface, if the user wish to buy a product from store using telephone service, then how can an admin add that transaction to user account and maintain store inventory?

Comment: can not understand? you need to create a new admin user and give permission for Catalog and sales,customer section

Comment: Once the user is registered I require an admin to be able to shop for a client through telephonic purchases instead of web interface on client's behalf for Cash on Delivery type orders.

As far I understood from your answer, an admin can do that, right?

Comment: yes.it possible...

Comment: You could create a order through the admin via Admin / Sales / Orders / Create new order -> choose your customer or create a new one, app products, choose send and paymethod and hit save. All out-of-the-box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is actually built into Magento by default.

It is called "assisted shopping" and your administrators can do it from the Magento backend.

You simply just login to the backend and go to Sales > Orders > Create New Order. The rest is pretty much self-explanatory.

There are extremely detailed instructions in how to do this on the Magento User Guide located:
[Magento CE User Guide](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#order-processing/shopping-assisted.html%3FTocPath%3DSales%2520%2526%2520Orders%7CAssisted%2520Shopping%7C_____0)

From your edit. The store will still need to go into the backend of Magento and do this process. There is no way around that. The inventory will still drop (assuming you are using Magento to manage inventory). If you have a POS system, you could look into integrating it with that, however from experience you should make sure your store is successful before investing in that kind of resources.